# Dismissing the keyboard with a uibutton when there are multiple text fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I know that I can resign a single text field to first responder when touching a button by implementing the following:

```
- (IBAction)signMeUpButton:(id)sender {


     [self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

However, In my case I have multiple text fields, and I feel like typing them in one at a time, cant possibly be the best way  / most modern way of doing so.

I reviewed multiple questions on the site, such as this one:

[iOS SDK: Dismiss keyboard when a button gets clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356979/ios-sdk-dismiss-keyboard-when-a-button-gets-clicked)

But none of them mention, having more than one text field and dismissing them with an `IBAction` ... What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: try this http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2013/05/20/snippet-finding-the-current-first-responder/

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
- (IBAction)signMeUpButton:(id)sender
{
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one text field, it's best to implement the following

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

So, in your case it would be :

```
    - (IBAction) signMeUpButton:(id)sender {
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
      }
```

That will do exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UITextField *currentTextField;


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      currentTextField = textField;
}

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
      [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: try this if([textField isFirstResponder]){
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
}  or   [[self view] endEditing:YES];

Comment: I think this solution better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029267/is-there-any-way-of-asking-an-ios-view-which-of-its-children-has-first-responder/14135456#14135456